# TLS 1.2. Handshake: Where do Client and Server negotiate how the master key is built from randoms and pre?

Tags: tls, handshake

I am currently trying to solve an exercise where I should look at a TLS 1.2 handshake trace while having access to pre and both randoms (server random and client random).

In order to decrypt application data, I need to rebuild the master key.

But I am struggling with finding the section where it is negotiated how this master key is actually built from pre and randoms.

How does TLS 1.2 handle that? Is there maybe a default handling?

Comment: That depends on the cipher suite

Comment: top hit for "tls 1.2 master key": https://www.cryptologie.net/article/340/tls-pre-master-secrets-and-master-secrets/

Comment: Please see the TLS 1.2 standard: [RFC 5246 section 8.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-8.1) has the suggesting title __"8.1.  Computing the Master Secret"__ . And there you can see that two methods exists - which one is chosen depends on the key exchange. And the type of key exchange depends on the negotiated cipher.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131724/the-first-few-milliseconds-of-an-https-connection-tls-1-2-tls-echde-rsa-with

Comment: Maybe TLS 1.2 Illustrated can help: https://tls.ulfheim.net/

Comment: My problem is, that I don't really know, what kind of PRF I need to use. As @SteffenUllrich suggested, that may depend on the negotiated cipher. So I will come back here when I know what information is needed to ask adequately.